# How to convert a codepen.io page into a Vue app

Tags: vue.js, codepen

I'm trying to convert from [this CodePen app](https://codepen.io/trevoreyre/pen/vbqpxv) to a Vue app. I'm new to Vue and can't quite figure out how to transplant the app successfully.

I've created a new `App.vue` file and tried to fill in the relevant sections like so:

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <autocomplete
      :search="search"
      placeholder="Search Wikipedia"
      aria-label="Search Wikipedia"
      :get-result-value="getResultValue"
      @submit="handleSubmit"
    ></autocomplete>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Autocomplete from '@trevoreyre/autocomplete-vue'
  const wikiUrl = 'https://en.wikipedia.org'
  const params = 'action=query&list=search&format=json&origin=*'
  export default {
    el: '#app',
    components: {
      Autocomplete
    },
    methods: {
      // Search function can return a promise
      // which resolves with an array of
      // results. In this case we're using
      // the Wikipedia search API.
      search(input) {
        const url = `${wikiUrl}/w/api.php?${
          params
        }&srsearch=${encodeURI(input)}`
        return new Promise(resolve => {
          if (input.length < 3) {
            return resolve([])
          }
          fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
              resolve(data.query.search)
            })
        })
      },
      // Wikipedia returns a format like this:
      //
      // {
      //   pageid: 12345,
      //   title: 'Article title',
      //   ...
      // }
      // 
      // We want to display the title
      getResultValue(result) {
        return result.title
      },
      // Open the selected article in
      // a new window
      handleSubmit(result) {
        window.open(`${wikiUrl}/wiki/${
          encodeURI(result.title)
        }`)
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style>
#app {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
```

I'm taking the import instructions from [here](https://autocomplete.trevoreyre.com/#/vue-component).

Note, that I have nothing in my `main.js` file since I'm not sure what should go there.

When I serve the app, I don't see anything, but I don't have any build errors. What's the right way of doing this?

Comment: If you initialise a project using the [Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html) and copy/paste your code into `App.vue`, you should be okay.

Comment: There's a fair amount of config involved with setting up a Vue app and the CLI takes care of it all for you.

Comment: Thanks Daniel! I did initialize this project via Vue CLI and nothing appears on localhost. Should I have anything in the `main.js` file, or everything in App.vue?

Comment: From my own experience, if you don't see anything either you must have error or your app configuration is not right?

Comment: Depending on if you're using Vue 2 or 3, in `main.js` there should be something along the lines of `new Vue({...` or `createApp(App)`.

Comment: @Parseltongue Just restore `main.js` to the original generated contents. You *need* that code to mount the `App.vue` component.

Comment: You're right @tony19. Thanks. That's all I needed to do